# Thread dump analysis: Unexpected behavior - Waiting threads

Tags: java, websphere, thread-dump

I am trying to go through the java thread dump. My application (hosted on websphere) is facing problems, where few threads are hung for indefinite time.

On investigation I could see below snippet where multiple threads are waiting for object which is not owned.

a) Why the threads are waiting on the object which is not owned?

b) What is the difference between WebContainer thread and ORB.thread.pool thread?

```
2LKMONINUSE      sys_mon_t:0x00007FC510A24818 infl_mon_t: 0x00007FC510A24890:
3LKMONOBJECT       java/lang/Object@0x00000001C4D927B8: <unowned>
3LKNOTIFYQ            Waiting to be notified:
3LKWAITNOTIFY            "ORB.thread.pool : 2" (J9VMThread:0x000000000BBDD200)
3LKWAITNOTIFY            "ORB.thread.pool : 3" (J9VMThread:0x000000000CB22200)
3LKWAITNOTIFY            "ORB.thread.pool : 4" (J9VMThread:0x000000000C9A1800)
3LKWAITNOTIFY            "ORB.thread.pool : 6" (J9VMThread:0x000000000C624C00)
3LKWAITNOTIFY            "ORB.thread.pool : 9" (J9VMThread:0x000000000CE5F400)
3LKWAITNOTIFY            "WebContainer : 13" (J9VMThread:0x000000000CD20000)
3LKWAITNOTIFY            "ORB.thread.pool : 11" (J9VMThread:0x000000000C61AA00)
3LKWAITNOTIFY            "ORB.thread.pool : 23" (J9VMThread:0x000000000CA0C200)
3LKWAITNOTIFY            "ORB.thread.pool : 25" (J9VMThread:0x000000000C216D00)
3LKWAITNOTIFY            "ORB.thread.pool : 26" (J9VMThread:0x000000000CA85000)
3LKWAITNOTIFY            "ORB.thread.pool : 27" (J9VMThread:0x000000000C4E8500)
```

Comment: webcontainer thread pool is for web requests (e.g. servlets, jsp, rest), orb.threadpool is for RMI calls (remote interface EJBs). You should be able to see the stacktrace if you load thread dump to TMDA (Thread and Monitor Dump Analyzer). It is waiting to be notified - so all these threads called wait() on some object, and are waiting for the notify() from the owner when it releases the lock.

Comment: You can identify which threads are idle by stacks: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21672204